# Hibernate ManyToMany doesn't find existing records

Tags: java, hibernate

I've got field annotated with

```
@ManyToOne(fetch= FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "orders_id")
public Order getOrder() {
    return order;
}
```

From opposite side I've got:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "order", cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, fetch = FetchType.LAZY) 
public Collection<OrderNewspaper> getOrderNewspapers() { return orderNewspapers; }
```

When I'm trying to find entity OrderNewspaper I've got:
Not found exception:
`Unable to find models.Order with id 84`

For sure records exists, but when before this em.find(OrderNewspaper.class,49) I run em.find(Order.class,84) everything is OK when I'm trying to get Order by getOrder.

What can be cause of such problem?

Comment: Paste the OneToMany side also

Comment: Ok, I've updated question